# How to install "Web Application Project support" for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

My root problem is that I get the following error message from my CruiseControl server :

```
errorMSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
```

I know all i have to do to workaround this issue is to copy the files to the folder but I just can't found anyone having thoses files and based on [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/fc5e7c6b-0ecd-4c5f-bda2-e5c7f19221a8)
I tried to "explicitly install the Web Application Project support on my machine" BUT I don't have such an option from the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Setup tool ...

Does anyone managed to install this component ? Otherwise where can I found the content of the following folder : C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\ ?

Comment: You'll find those files on a developer machine where VS 2010 is installed. But on a 64 bit system the files are located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scordo said :

You'll find those files on a developer machine where VS 2010 is installed. But on a 64 bit system the files are located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications